# pycharm logging to file in test mode

Tags: python, logging, pycharm

I have a problem with generating log files while using the test runner and I can't wrap my head around it. Basically, if I execute my test function with pytest, no log file is created. If I run the function as a script call (so normal run "test_logger", instead of run "pytest for test_logger.test_logging") the logging file is generated as expected.

As you can see in the example below it is not a complicated logger. I assume the problem has something to do with the pytest configuration but I just don't understand what is going wrong here.

I did see that Pycharm offers options for logging the console output to file etc., but I want to understand why file generation via the logging module is somehow suppressed. E.g. if I build a big e2e test to simulate correct behavior of my app I want to have everything happening like for the real thing which means in this case: generate the log where I want it and how I want it. I know that I can circumvent the issue by just running the test as a normal script but that does not help me understanding why this issue is happening in the first place.

```
import os
import datetime
import logging


def test_logging():
    LOG_PATH = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'log')

    if not os.path.exists(LOG_PATH):
        os.mkdir(LOG_PATH)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    filename = os.path.join(LOG_PATH, 'log-'+now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M")+'.log')

    logging.basicConfig(filename=filename, level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
    logger = logging.getLogger()

    logger.debug("Test")

test_logging()
```